# Login is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written the code below for a login page, but doesn't seem to work.
The variable `temp` takes a value of `0`.

```
protected void ButtonSbmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //if (IsPostBack) {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string cmdstr = "select count(*) from Registration where username='" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand checkuser = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);       

    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(checkuser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    if (temp == 1) {

        string str = "select password from Registration where username='" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand pass = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
        string pass1 = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();

        if (pass1 == TextBoxPassword.Text) {
            Session["new"] = TextBoxUsername.Text;
            Response.Redirect("secure.aspx");
        } else {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "invalid password";
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working". What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Also, note that storing passwords in a database, especially as cleartext, is so bad an idea as to border on criminally negligent. Please tell me this isn't a production system.

Comment: Well, for starters, you have a huge SQL injection vulnerability.  So I'd say the fact that people aren't logging in is a bit of a good thing at the moment...

Comment: Also, why are you hitting the database twice for nearly identical data?  You only need to hit it once.

Comment: You don't need to hit Twice to your DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ASP.NET membership provider, and the ASP.NET login controls along with ASP.NET forms authentication. This is built-in functionality that ASP.NET provides; it works, it's secure, and you don't have to write the SQL statements and logic.

Lesson one on security - if there is built-in functionality, use it. It will always be better than starting to write your own.